# Modal View change my Tab when it close

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, tabbar

I have a TabBarViewController with 2 tabs: tab(A) and tab(B). Both tabs has UITableView inside and when I click in a cell, a modal view appears. If I click on the tab(A) which is the default tab, everything works fine but the problem is when I go to Tab(B) and after opening a modal view, when I close the modal view the tab bar automatically goes back to the default tab which is tab(A). 
I tried :

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and also :

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                      completion:nil];
```

for going back. but I have same result.

Comment: Are you overriding `viewWillAppear` in your view controller subclass? And, where do you set tab A to be "default"?

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, and there's nothing wrong with the way you're going back. How are you presenting the modal view controller? If in code, post that.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the last view controller selected in the tab bar as such:

```
    -(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
         _previousViewControllerIndex = // get index of your tab here
    }
```

After dismissing the model view, viewDidAppear will be called on your  UITabBarController, and you can programatically select the previous selected controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:_previousViewControllerIndex];
}
```